# Html tool like Qweb from Odoo

Tags: html, html-rendering, qweb

I've worked like a year with OpenERP now Odoo, and I found the QWeb tool really useful. But now that I'm leaving Odoo I would like to find a tool like [QWeb](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html).
That is why I come here, to ask you experienced developers if you know a similar tool like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"like" qweb is all the ones that are xml-based, you can find a full list here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system

But BTW, leave Odoo to do "Things like Odoo does" is extrange, stay in odoo :-) you can doo almost all you want there.

Answer (score 1):

QWeb is nicer templating tool and it was created by Odoo and its designed to work cross language originally which can be forked from [git - qweb](https://github.com/antonylesuisse/qweb). Original framework is designed to work with CSharp, JavaScript, PHP, Python, Ruby so wtih your technical abilities you can fork and maintain your own qweb templating tool.

Or else, You can choose between thousands of templating tools available on all programming languages